# Fazer o batch dizer o nome do exe

Tags: cmd, batch

eu quero saber como que um batch, diga o nome do exe que eu quero.

Eu tentei, mas não deu muito certo

Meu Script:

```
where /r C:\Users\Usuario\ *.txt
```

Mas esse comando, diz o caminho completo. eu quero que diga só o nome

**Exemplo:**

**Teste.exe**

É só isso, eu sou médio em script de batch, Valeu!

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Você pode usar o where dentro de um for, ficaria algo assim:

for /f "Delims=" %%a in ('where /r "c:\users\usuario" *.txt') do @echo %%~nxa

Comment: Valeu!!! funcionou.

Answer (score 2):

faça dessa maneira se for dentro de um script:

```
for %%F in (teste.exe) do (echo.%%~nF)
```

**o resultado será:**
teste

e caso queira puxar junto com a extensão...

```
for %%F in (teste.exe) do (echo.%%~nxF)
```

**o resultado será:**
teste.exe

veja que eu acrescentei a letra **x**, que indica que quero buscar a extensão.
caso eu queira buscar o tamanho do arquivo, posso adicionar a letra **z**.
e eu terei o tamanho em bytes.

```
for %%F in (teste.exe) do (echo.%%~nxzF)
```

basicamente você adiciona uma letra no meio da variável do for `%%'aqui'F`
com o prefixo **~**

**veja outros exemplos retirados do prompt**

```
%~I         - expande %I removendo quaisquer aspas em volta (")
%~fI        - expande %I para um nome de caminho totalmente qualificado
%~dI        - expande %I para somente uma letra de unidade
%~pI        - expande %I para somente um caminho
%~nI        - expande %I para somente um nome de arquivo
%~xI        - expande %I para somente uma extensão de arquivo
%~sI        - o caminho expandido contém somente nomes curtos
%~aI        - expande %I para atributos de arquivo do arquivo
%~tI        - expande %I para data/hora do arquivo
%~zI        - expande %I para o tamanho do arquivo
```

Comment: Não quero o echo, só quero os nomes do exe em um diretorio.

Comment: bom, nesse caso você pode usar o operador > ou >> caso não queira sobscrever. o echo. foi só pra exibir o resultado, eu mostrei para você uma maneira de exibir apenas o nome, aqui não podemos montar scripts, apenas tirar dúvidas